# web.release.config change dynamic webservice url

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, release, publish

I'm editing my web.release.config file for production. I want the web.config file changed after a publish.
I found how to change the web.config by using the web.release.config file properly, but not for this particular component.

The URL of an dynamic webservice has to change.

In the web.config:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <FooService.Properties.Settings>    
        <setting name="FooService_Student" serializeAs="String">  
            <value>http://testwebservices.foo.bar.nl/Student.asmx</value>  
        </setting>  
        <setting name="FooService_User" serializeAs="String">  
            <value>http://testwebservices.foo.bar.nl/User.asmx</value>  
         </setting>  
    </FooService.Properties.Settings>  
</applicationSettings>
```

now, how do I change the `<value>` in both settings? I tried the following, but that didn't work out:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <applicationSettings>
        <FooService.Properties.Settings>    
            <setting name="FooService_Student" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace">  
                <value>http://webservices.foo.bar.nl/Student.asmx</value>  
            </setting>  
            <setting name="FooService_User" serializeAs="String" xdt:Transform="Replace">  
                 <value>http://webservices.foo.bar.nl/User.asmx</value>  
            </setting>  
        </FooService.Properties.Settings>  
    </applicationSettings>
 </configuration>
```

Anyone experience with this matter?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

Add `xdt:Transform="Replace"` to the `applicationSettings` tag.

```
<applicationSettings xdt:Transform="Replace"> 
<FooService.Properties.Settings>     
    <setting name="FooService_Student" serializeAs="String">   
        <value>http://webservices.foo.bar.nl/Student.asmx</value>   
    </setting>   
    <setting name="FooService_User" serializeAs="String">   
        <value>http://webservices.foo.bar.nl/User.asmx</value>   
     </setting>   
</FooService.Properties.Settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a `xdt:Locator="Match(name)"`, that will probably be what you need to find the exact nodes to replace.

Comment: This should be combined with the above answer to provide a more general (and correct) approach to the problem. Thanks for sharing, sir.